# How to add a secondary declaration to XML in R

Tags: xml, r, svg

I am writing SVGs (scalable vector graphics) in R that are part of a web application, and would like to point styling of the svg to an external CSS file. I am using the XML package in R to build these files. I a struggling to add the declaration that points to the CSS programmatically (short of sliding it in there with cat() )
Here is what I would like to add to the top of the XML document:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="../css/main.css" ?>
```